# Why am I not receiving email notifications from Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, email-notification

When people comment or answer, I no longer receive email notifications.  Why?

Comment: Did you change OpenIDs recently or anything like that?  How long has it been?

Comment: (the irony is, you may never receive notification of this comment)

Comment: That's not a lot to work with. *Any* details?

Comment: Possibly your email address is not confirmed.

Comment: It seemed to work fine several months ago, and the email address still works -- at least when testing for trace -- so I'm not sure what could be causing this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only receive email notifications if:

1. You have **first enabled email notifications in the global inbox:**

[![][1]][1]
<sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/global-inbox-email-link.png))</sub>

2. And you have **not clicked on the global inbox for the specified time period**. In other words, if you specified "daily" then you must not have clicked on the inbox with your mouse for at least 24 hours to begin getting email notifications. In other words, every single click on the global inbox resets this timer to zero.

See https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/10/improved-global-email-notifications/
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqy4c.png

Comment: thanks...I'm still bouncing around trying to find the global inbox...let me try that....

Comment: yeah, that might be it --- i guess it got set to zero, not sure how, but had been using notifications...this should work now, thakns

Comment: Is there a more up-to-date description somewhere of the way the notification system now works with the current site design? I'm looking for answers to the same question but for the current site.

Comment: Hey, getting page not found in the first link.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't get email notifications immediately. You should get Stack Exchange Inbox messages and (daily|each 3 hours|weekly) notifications by email if you requested them. Are you sure you have selected "Would you like to have responses to your questions sent to you via email?" when sending a question?

Comment: yes I was receiving them before, but now I haven't received in weeks....